# Can't add Motion Blur to layer imported from Photoshop

Tags: after-effects

I can't enable Motion Blur on this layer:

[image]

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Thats because you have the collapse transformations button ticked:** 
[image: Collapse Transformation]

When [collapse transformations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AfterEffects/9.0/WS064964FC-424C-4e5a-A5C3-2160B3DFBCA4a.html) is ticked After Effects takes the options of the layers **inside** the 'loader' composition. So you will need to open up the 'loader' composition (double click) and then you can enable motion blur on the layers inside.

When you import Photoshop documents into After Effects as compositions, any groups in the PSD become pre-comps within AE.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click your "loader"-layer and choose Pre-Compose Layer and choose Move all atributes into the new composition, you should be able to put motion blur on it.

And just a tip: If you for some reason in some situations can't use blurs, often because of motion generated by effects, you can use CC Force Motion Blur to force motion blur to your footage.